# New Theme support for IE10

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.2

I have a mobile application developed using Sencha Touch 2.0 version. These days I tried to switch to the latest Sencha library (2.2.1) to support theme depending on the user platform.

My question is related to Windows phone theme and IE 10.

By default, I get in IE 10 a theme like in this:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/example/nested-list

But theme that I want to have it on IE 10 is this one:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/example/kitchen-sink

Does someone know what to do or what is different in Kitchen-sink app to have the same theme in IE 10?

What am I missing?

Comment: Both of your links load the default Sencha Touch theme. Which theme do you want to load? Perhaps this question/answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16998586/273985

Comment: @rdougan: thanks for your answer! I want to load Windows 8 theme in IE 10. I updated app.json with the changes from http://stackoverflow.com/a/16998586/273985, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your app.scss file.
the first couple lines include ..\default and \default\all themes.
change these to \windows and \windows\all ...in other words change the word "default" to "windows"; then save as app_ie.scss or whatever.

Then the app.json does need to change as well so that the platform ie10 is recognized and your proper app_ie.css is loaded when ie10 is the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Change your app-scss like this:

```
$dark-theme: false;
$base-color: #2672EC;

@import 'sencha-touch/windows';
@import 'sencha-touch/windows/all';

$background-color: #fff !default;
$primary-text-color: #000 !default;
$secondary-text-color: #000 !default;
```

This will  make the ie theme light theme.