# How to load sencha-touch.css in IE 10?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am using the latest sencha touch library (2.2.1). I tried to load default theme in IE10, which is sencha-touch.css ( apple look and feel ), and IE 10 just crashes.

I saw that in Kitchen Sink example:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/touch-build/examples/kitchensink/index.html?platform=chrome

it is possible to choose from Theme -> "Sencha" option.

Does any one know if they do something different?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `app.json` to only load that theme on all platforms (or just IE10). You can do this by modifying the `CSS` property:

```
"css": [
    {
        "path": "resources/css/sencha-touch.css",
        "platform": ["chrome", "safari", "android", "firefox", "ie10"],
        "theme": "Default",
        "update": "delta"
    }
],
```

Comment: On Chrome browser it works fine, but only in IE 10 the app it's not responsive when I try to navigate on a nested list. I have to force IE10 to close. Login page works properly and I have no issue on Chrome or IE10.

Comment: Very strange - that exact example works fine for me in IE10, even with the `platform` parameter. Are you using the `platform` parameter?

Comment: No,for my application I only replaced the old sencha library with the latest one and load sencha-touch.css, instead of apple.css which came with the old library. "Kitchen" example works for me too, but I don't know if they make other changes to work in IE10 when I choose "Theme->Sencha" or "Auto Detect". I saw that it loads in IE10 the "sencha-touch.css" and in development.js it sets the "Ext.theme" to default. My application is build in VS 2010 with MVC 2 structure. I created myself a app.json file and put it in Root of the application structure having the "css" configuration from above.

Comment: ...putting the "app.json" file in Root of the application structure still does not help. Whenever I try to navigate my nested list view in IE10, "Not responding" appears in IE window title bar. Because I load application with Sencha default theme, something does not work properly in UI. If I modified app.json to load "wp.css", I have no issue navigating in IE

Comment: The default theme is designed to work on all platforms/browsers, therefor it should not cause the browser to freeze. It sounds like there is JS logic happening in your application, when the default theme is used, which causes the browser to crash. Perhaps you need to start looking at your applications code directly and see what is causing it. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: I found what causes IE 10 to froze when try to load "sencha-touch.css". After two days of investigation, I copied CSS code below from "wp.css" to "sencha-touch.css" (both from css-debug folder) and it works:                                                         .x-button-forward .x-button-label, .x-button-forward .x-badge,
.x-button-back .x-button-label, .x-button-back .x-badge {
  display: none;
}

Comment: Hi Costinel, I have copied that css class properties to sencha-touch.css file. Now, I am able to run the app in IE10. Thanks for your comment. The ".x-button-back .x-button-label" class set to "display:none".So, the back button doesn't show the text. If i remove that particular class from "sencha-touch.css" file, the IE again stops responding. How do i resolve this? pls help me to resolve this issue.